# Are program-specific ports open when the program is deactivated? Why?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

Basic questions. If I have a unique port open through port-forwarding for a program like Minecraft, is that port open when Minecraft is deactivated? Whatever the answer, why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What [John says in his answer](https://superuser.com/a/1673787/167207) is correct, but doesn't seem quite responsive to the question.

When people talk about a port being open, what they really mean is that there is a reachable port that will accept input which will be processed by a program. In order for network communication to occur, you need the **Three P's**: a **Program** that has created a **Port**, that is accessible by a **Pathway** between the two systems.

Ports are established by Programs, not things like firewalls or NAT configurations (those only address the **Pathway**), so if there isn't a process that has established a port with the OS and bound it to one or more IP interfaces on the system in question, the port is closed. It will not accept traffic, and even if it did, there isn't a program that will use that port for I/O. The OS will ignore any data sent to the port because the OS has no means to deal with it.

This is evident if you use a remote port scanner like [ShieldsUp](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) or a testing tool like [canyouseeme.org](https://canyouseeme.org/). Try scanning your port while Minecraft is running and it will report open. If you scan it again when Minecraft is not running, you will see it report the port as closed.

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation. A small clarification: when you say "It will not accept traffic", what is "it"?

Comment: In this case, It is the port (perhaps more specifically the OS TCP\IP stack; Ports are really just IO streams, so the stack would handle what happens when you try to write to a stream that doesn't exist).

Answer (score 1):

If you opened the port separately from Minecraft (the implication in your post is that you did), then the port (for port forwarding) will remain open.

Type netstat -ab in an admin command prompt to see what ports are listening.

You will need to close it (the way you opened it) if you do not want it open.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you opened it in your Router \ Modem \ Windows Firewall

An open port doesn't necessarily post a security issue, but a port scanner could determine what kind of programs or services you are using and try to explore it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "open". Take Nmap (a commonly used port scanner) and the definitions it uses (from Nmap Reference Guide, [Port Scanning Basics](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html); emphasis mine):

> The six port states recognized by Nmap
>
> - **open**
>   **An application is actively accepting TCP connections, UDP datagrams or SCTP associations on this port.** Finding these is often the primary goal of port scanning. Security-minded people know that each open port is an avenue for attack. Attackers and pen-testers want to exploit the open ports, while administrators try to close or protect them with firewalls without thwarting legitimate users. Open ports are also interesting for non-security scans because they show services available for use on the network.
> - **closed**
>   A closed port is accessible (it receives and responds to Nmap probe packets), but **there is no application listening on it.** They can be helpful in showing that a host is up on an IP address (host discovery, or ping scanning), and as part of OS detection. Because closed ports are reachable, it may be worth scanning later in case some open up. Administrators may want to consider blocking such ports with a firewall. Then they would appear in the filtered state, discussed next.
> - filtered
>   Nmap cannot determine whether the port is open because packet filtering prevents its probes from reaching the port. The filtering could be from a dedicated firewall device, router rules, or host-based firewall software. These ports frustrate attackers because they provide so little information. Sometimes they respond with ICMP error messages such as type 3 code 13 (destination unreachable: communication administratively prohibited), but filters that simply drop probes without responding are far more common. […]
> - unfiltered
>   The unfiltered state means that a port is accessible, but Nmap is unable to determine whether it is open or closed. Only the ACK scan, which is used to map firewall rulesets, classifies ports into this state. Scanning unfiltered ports with other scan types such as Window scan, SYN scan, or FIN scan, may help resolve whether the port is open.
> - open|filtered
>   Nmap places ports in this state when it is unable to determine whether a port is open or filtered. […]
> - closed|filtered
>   This state is used when Nmap is unable to determine whether a port is closed or filtered. […]

In these terms the answer to your question

> is that port open when Minecraft is deactivated?

is: no, the port is not open, it is closed. Why is that so? By definition. :)

---

Answers claiming your port without Minecraft running is open apparently use the word "open" for what Nmap considers "anything but filtered". I guess they would use "closed" for what Nmap defines as "filtered". These answers are not necessarily wrong; they just seem to understand "open vs closed" differently.

[This other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1673804/432690), where it states

> When people talk about a port being open, what they really mean is that there is a reachable port that will accept input which will be processed by a program. […] if there isn't a process that has established a port with the OS and bound it to one or more IP interfaces on the system in question, the port is closed.

basically agrees with Nmap.